# What is RhoMobile for?

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I do not understand.  I have to download xcode and bunches of other stuff to make it work.  I don't understand what I'm getting.  Is it that I can use Ruby instead of Objective-C and it compiles down to a native app?  Thanks.

Comment: why the close?  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhomobile, selected Best Startup at Interop 2009, lets developers use HTML and Ruby to create native iPhone, BlackBerry, Windows Mobile, Symbian, and Android applications.

The development in it is called rhodes.
Rhodes is a free and open source MVC-based framework written in Ruby under the MIT license for building native cross-platform mobile development applications. Rhodes enables developers to harness their traditional web skills such as HTML, HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript, instead of in Objective-C or other complex native device OS language, to create a native app, and porting the app in cross operating systems such as Android, Apple’s iPhone and iPad, BlackBerry, Windows Mobile, Symbian and HP/Palm's Linux-based WebOS.

Download rhoStudio. Using the rhoStudio you can create your iOS, android,BB,WP application easily.
What you have to do is to code in simple html, javascript and if you want to use MVC architecture you have to use Ruby for that. As it is build on Ruby framework.

Good thing is it also supports HTML 5.
Once you build the project you can transform into any of your favorite device application.
with just only couple of commands.

I just coded in html in rhoStudio and now I can run the same application in my Xcode also. its fun.
At the same time of development you can run your project for other devices too.

Answer (score 3):

The ruby that you write is compiled to Ruby bytecode and the compiled bytecode is executed as a resource by Rhodes and compiled to native code. A rubyVM interpreter is integrated into the application.